# How to write a transaction using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to write a transaction. An employee can book a holiday. But after this I have to make sure the holiday is subtracted from his holiday account :) That is why I need a transaction.

So I found this code to do it in hibernate 5. It seems that is the most ususal approach

```
Transaction transObj = null;
        Session sessionObj = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        try {  
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            sessionObj = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transObj = sessionObj.beginTransaction();

        holidayDao.save(holiday);
        user.setVacationDays(user.getVacationDays() - holiday.getNumberOfDays());
        userDao.save(user);

        transObj.commit(); 

        }catch (Exception ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
            transObj.rollback();  
            }  
            finally {sessionObj.close();}
```

My project is quite big. I did not have to use an hibernate.cfg.xml file so far. For transaction all of a sudden I need to use one. So I just want to write a hibernate.cfg.xml that my transaction will work later. So how must I do that. Is there no other way in hibernate to make transactions work beside having a hibernate.cfg.xml file. Thanks for your help.

So I already have a database.properties file . (I am using Spring).

But now to get SessionFactory work I will create a hibernate.cfg.xml file
which basically has the same properties which are already in my database.properties file.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, so what is your problem? Please include your test code in the question

Comment: First I wanted to know that this is the way you write a Transaction in java. Second I need a hibernate.cfg.xml  file. So far I did not need one. So what should I put there. Remember I just want to get sessionFactory to work.

Comment: *"For transaction all of a sudden I need to use one."* - Why, what problem are you running into? The snippet of code you show is a way to manually create a session and transaction from plain Java code through the Hibernate API. So where in that process does the need for the xml configuration file come in?

Comment: sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  This gives me exception and says it cannot find hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Check if application resource 'hibernate.cfg.xml' is in under resources folder.

Comment: no there is none because I never needed it before. My application was running without it. Just for this sessionFactory I seem to need it.

Comment: Now I justed created an empty hibernate.cfg.xml file and this code here gives me Null Pointer Exception.    Configuration config = new Configuration();
   Configuration config1 = config.configure();